# "handleClinet" Namespace missing

Tags: c#, networking, namespaces

Im working on a small chat section for a program of mine and following a tutorial to do so. However, I came across a call to a namespace I dont seem to have access to for some reason. The namespace "handleClinet" doesnt exist in SharpDevelop for whatever reason. Is there a way I can get my hands on it?

Comment: How could anyone answer your question when you don't even point us to the tutorial you're following?

Comment: Or provide us with the code that you are getting the error on? I work a lot with SharpDevelop, and that namespace does not look familiar to me, but it does look like a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The `handleClinet` is a class in the example code.

There seems to be plenty of people following the same tutorial where a class is misspelt as `handleClinet` instead of `handleClient`.

The code seems to be copied to several places, for example here: http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server.htm

The lower half of the code is the `handleClinet` class.